# Running Cypress in Bitbucket pipelines fails looking for chrome

Tags: continuous-integration, cypress, bitbucket-pipelines

I have no idea why it tries to run Chrome instead of Electron based browser. Could be a Percy culprit here?

```
+ yarn cy:ci --parallel --ci-build-id $BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
yarn run v1.13.0
$ cd cypress && yarn ci --parallel --ci-build-id 119
$ percy exec -- cypress run --record --parallel --ci-build-id 119
[percy] created build #5: https://percy.io/DeepVision/doveze-cz/builds/1794467
Error: Failed to launch chrome!
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/cypress/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-650583/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md
    at onClose (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/cypress/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:342:14)
    at Interface.helper.addEventListener (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/cypress/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:331:50)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

More info and configs at gist: https://gist.github.com/FredyC/d5b82b485e65245102dd24f6df787f5f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help from Percy support, this issue is overcome by using the image `cypress/browsers:chrome67-ff57`.

Comment: Hi can you please share complete pipeline yaml how we create complete pipeline yaml file for cypress tests ?